# Json response working in one function. and not the next?

Tags: javascript

I have put the code below my for a simple weather app using Open Weather

The code to get the icon code from the JSON works in the first block but not in the second?
i can console log the variable no problem but when i am trying to display the icon it isnt loading the png file?

The line in question is

```
let icon1 = jsonResponse.list[8].weather[0].icon 
nextDayWeather.src = `/resources/icons/${icon1}.png`
```

full code for reference including same code working in an earlier function

```
async function getWeather(input) {
    const city = input
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=`)
        if (response.ok) {
            const jsonResponse = await response.json()
            const {icon} = jsonResponse.weather[0]
                currTemp.innerText = Math.floor(jsonResponse.main.temp - 273)
                currWind.innerText = jsonResponse.wind.speed
                currWeather.src = `/resources/icons/${icon}.png`
                
            return
        }
        throw new Error('Request Failed')

    }  catch(error) {
        window.location = '/'
    }
}

async function extraWeather(input) { 
    const city = input
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&appid=`)
            if (response.ok){
                const jsonResponse = await response.json()              
                let icon1 = jsonResponse.list[8].weather[0].icon 
                let icon2 = jsonResponse.list[16].weather[0].icon
                let icon3 = jsonResponse.list[24].weather[0].icon       
                nextDayWeather.src = `/resources/icons/${icon1}.png`        //needs fixing??
                nextDayWind.innerText = jsonResponse.list[8].wind.speed
                nextDayTemp.innerText = Math.floor(jsonResponse.list[8].main.temp - 273)
                nextDayWeather2.src = `/resources/icons/${icon2}.png`
                nextDayWind2.innerText = jsonResponse.list[16].wind.speed
                nextDayTemp2.innerText = Math.floor(jsonResponse.list[16].main.temp - 273)
                nextDayWeather3.src = `/resources/icons/${icon3}.png`
                nextDayWind3.innerText = jsonResponse.list[24].wind.speed
                nextDayTemp3.innerText = Math.floor(jsonResponse.list[24].main.temp - 273)
                console.log(jsonResponse.list[16].weather[0].icon)
                return
            
        }
        throw new Error ('error') }
        catch(error){
    console.log(error)
}
}
```

Comment: So assuming  the fetch works, please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] with just an example of the object and your parsing code

Comment: What is the type of all the variables? Like currWether, nextWether, nextWhether2 .. what are all these?

Comment: The fetch works and I can console log the results, all the other data works fine, just the image wont load in the first code block i posted.  In 'getWeather' it works perfectly.  in ' extraWeather' it doesn't and it's almost identical code.  I cant post it to replicate without posting my API key

Comment: currWeather etc are all DOM elements. currWeather is an image i am trying to change the source of. I can change it to a string or anything I want so the code "works" in that respect.

Comment: did you log the result of `/resources/icons/${icon1}.png` and see if the path makes sense and the icon exists there?

Comment: fixed. Spent a long time looking at the JS and the HTML had an error. my mistake. thanks everyone